# "Parellelizing" a task involving pOpen

Tags: python, parallel-processing, fortran, scientific-computing

I am trying to solve an issue for my research group using a Python script. Our lab's code is written in Fortran 77. The code is essentially a black box for this task. We provide it 5 input values, it spits out 5 output values. These output values are compared to ground truth. We adjust the 5 input values until we receive output values that are approximately equal to our ground truth.

The way this process works is as follows: We write 5 input values to a .txt file. We execute the .exe for the code, which reads the input .txt. Code spits out a bunch of info, including values we compare to ground truth to judge how good those input values were. We adjust input values and re-run the .exe. And so on.

This task often takes hours because there is a highly non-linear equation hiding in this black box program. There are also logarithms and sqrts that can crash the program, i.e., the 5-dimensional space of input values includes areas that can crash the program.

Normal SciPy optimization algorithms can't seem to handle the crashyness of the program and never converge. So, I've written a script that basically brute forces an approx. solution and later runs the built-in optimization scripts on the approx. solution because I know/hope the approx. solution is not near an area that will crash the program.

This also takes hours because the code has to run the .exe every time, and it's reading from a single .txt, so I don't imagine being able to parallelize this task in a traditional manner. I use pOpen to open the exe in the script, and typical open("balance.txt","w") commands to open the file for writing, etc.

Are there any solutions for this type of problem, i.e., speeding up a search given an .exe that has to pull in a .txt file each time it runs? Aside from manually making 4 copies of my code, splitting up the search space of the .py script in 1/4ths, and having them all run independently (assuming a 4-core system)?

EDIT: Here is essentially the code:

```
def writeInput(Input):
    f=open("input.txt","w")
    f.write(Input)
    f.close()

def grabOutput():
    ps=Popen("code.exe",shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    for line in iter(ps.stdout.readline,''):
        **Iterate through .exe output finding 5 output values**

    result = np.array(5 values read by above)
    return result

def mainFunc(Input):

# f(x) -> f required by optimization algorithms for minimization

    global criteria

    writeInput(Input)
    result=grabOutput()

    ###################################
    # Omitted optimization function related stuff
    ####################################
    residual = result - criteria
    return residual

################################################
#  Main code
################################################

bounds=[(0.1,4.),(0.1,4.),(-4.,4.),(-.4,4.),(0.1,1.)]    
x0=np.array([1.,1.,1.,0.5,0.5])
criteria=np.array([0.26,5.49e19,1.0e20,1870.,587.])

flag=False
while flag==False:

    try:
        # Optimization routine that uses just an initial guess

        answer=broyden1(mainFunc,x0)

        # Could also use
        # answer=differential_evolution(mainFunc,bounds)
        # if I wanted to specify the bounds of the input space
        # which is why I also specify bounds=[...] above.


        print "answer = ",answer
        flag=True
    except:
        continue
```

Comment: You should show the cose of your script. How long doest the reading take?

Comment: Welcome to http://stackoverflow.com: could you read [ask] and [mcve] please?

Comment: how long does the exe take to run?  Unless it is very very fast the overhead of passing values via file i/o as you are is probably not an issue. If you are not willing to learn enough fortran to change it you dont seem to have any choice anyway.

Comment: The .exe takes about 1 second to run. The problem is that I am not entirely aware of any ways to parallelize the code internally. This is Fortran 77, and the code is possibly the most poorly documented code I've ever seen in my life. Our advisor uses things like "XX", "YY", "XYX", "XXYY2" as variable names for example, and it's roughly 40k lines (with no documentation).